# How should i design my workflow so that taks can run parallel

Tags: .net-4.0, parallel-processing, workflow-foundation-4

**how to design parallel processing workflow**

I have a scenarial case about data analysis.

There are four steps basicly:

1. pick up task either read from a queue or receive a message throught API (web service maybe) to trigger the service
2. submit request to remote service base on the parameters from step 1
3. wait from remote service finished and download
4. perform process on the data that downloaded from step 3

the four step above looks like a sequence workflow.
my question is that how can i scale it out.

every day i might need to perform hundreds to thousands of this task.
if i can do them in parallel,  that will help a lot. 
e.g run 20 tasks at a time.

so can we config  windows workflow foundation to run parallel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use pfx (http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx), then you can control how many threads to make for fetching, and using PLINQ I find helpful.

So, you loop over the list of urls, perhaps reading from a file or database, and then in your select you can then call a function to do the processing.

If you can go into more detail as to whether you want to have the fetching and processing be on different threads, for example, it may be easier to give a more complete answer.

**UPDATE:**

This is how I would approach this, but I am also using `ConcurrentQueue` (http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-system_collections_concurrent_concurrentqueue) so I can be putting data into the queue while reading from it.

This way each thread can dequeue safely, without worrying about having to lock your collection.

```
            Parallel.For(0, queue.Count, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 },
                (j) =>
                {
                   String i;
                   queue.TryDequeue(out i);
                   // call out to URL
                   // process data
                }
            });
```

You may want to put the data into another concurrent collection and have that be processed separately, it depends on your application needs.

Comment: Hi James,  i think the point that i choose to use workflow is to simplify my programming ... so that i can avoid dealing with those parallel programming stuff...instead, achieve it when i archetect it....  i want to treat the whole workflow as one task... so that whenever a task is called.. a thread will responsible for one workflow... just like webservice.... ... not sure what i think it right... thank you for your reply ...

Comment: Use PFX will simplify your coding though, and PLINQ is so helpful, as it abstracts out the threads even more.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way your tasks and workflow is modeled you can use a Parallel activity and create different branches for the different tasks to be performed. Each branch has its own logic and the WF runtime will start a second WCF request to retrieve data as soon as it is waiting for the first to respond. This requires you to model the number of branches explicitly but allows for different activities in each branch.

But from you description it sounds like you have the same steps for each task and in that case you could model it using a ParallelForEach activity and have that iterate over a collection of tasks. Each task object would need to contain all the information used for the request. This requires each task to have the same steps but you can put in as many tasks as you want.

What works best really depends on your scenario.